# How to sketch a non-function graph

Tags: plotting

I tried to plot roots of my equations with `Plot`, but because these graphs are not functions in some region Mathematica can not handle it.
How can I sketch my equation?

```
Plot[n /. NSolve[n (1/4 + (a - 6 n/10^3)^2) == 40 && n > 0, Reals], {a, -3, 3}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ContourPlot[n (1/4 + (a - 6 n/10^3)^2) == 40, {a, -3, 3}, {n, 0, 170}]
```

does the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = n /. Solve[n (1/4 + (a - 6 n/10^3)^2) == 40 && n > 0, n, Reals];
```

There are three roots

```
Length@sol

(* 3 *)
```

To see the full curve you need to increase the function sampling  ([`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) option) particularly at transitions between the solutions ([`MaxRecursions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursions.html) option)

```
Plot[Evaluate[sol], {a, -3, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, n}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.25, 0.6}]]
```

[image]